# Getting input with IUP in Lua

Tags: lua, iup

I've been trying to get input with IUP to make a small pong game.  I wanted to try some input, and tried some of the code that comes with the IUPGL examples, but the input doesn't seem to be working at all.  Here's the code as it stands so far:

```
require "iuplua"
require "iupluagl"
require "luagl"

paddle = {x = -0.9, y = 0.2}

function drawPaddle(x, y)
    gl.Begin(gl.QUADS)
    gl.Color(0.0, 0.5, 0.0)

    gl.Vertex(x, y)
    gl.Vertex(x + 0.1, y)
    gl.Vertex(x + 0.1, y - 0.4)
    gl.Vertex(x, y - 0.4)
end

canvas = iup.glcanvas{buffer = "DOUBLE", rastersize = "300x300"}

function canvas:action(x, y)
    iup.GLMakeCurrent(self)
    gl.ClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    gl.Clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    gl.MatrixMode(gl.PROJECTION)
    gl.Viewport(0, 0, 300, 300)
    gl.LoadIdentity()

    drawPaddle(paddle.x, paddle.y)

    gl.End()
    iup.GLSwapBuffers(self)
end

window = iup.dialog{canvas, title = "Soon to be Pong"}

function canvas:k_any(c)
    if c == iup.K_q then
        return iup.CLOSE
    elseif c == iup.K_w then
        paddle.y = paddle.y + 0.02
        return iup.CONTINUE
    else
        return iup.DEFAULT
    end
end

window:show()

iup.MainLoop()
```

It's my understanding that `canvas:k_any()` gets called when a key is pressed, but it's not responding, even to the quit command.  Any ideas?

Comment: You probably should ask this question to IUP mailing list

http://lists.luaforge.net/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/iup-mail

or to Lua mailing list

http://bazar2.conectiva.com.br/mailman/listinfo/lua

IUP authors are reading them, and usually are very helpful and responsive.

Comment: I use IUP in several projects, but haven't played with IUPGL at all as yet. Although, I probably should have used it instead of CD for an audio level meter control I had to implement for one project.... I do know that the key callbacks are quirkier in the Lua binding than they are when using IUP directly from C, so that might be a place to start looking in the source code. I'll second the recommendation to try the IUP list. The authors typically respond rapidly, and you'll reach a number of advanced users as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is at least part of the problem for the sample you've quoted. Before the IUP keyname constants are actually defined in your `iup` table, you need to call a function. The idea is that the memory footprint is lower if you don't need all of the key names, which many applications can do entirely without.

Try adding the following lines sometime shortly after `require "iuplua"` and before you use the names in any code:

```
iup.key_open()      -- load key names
```

This is documented near the top of the topic **Keyboard Codes** as well as in a variety of places related to the keyboard.

Without the call to `iup.key_open()`, `iup.K_q` evaluates to `nil` (as does any other key name) and thus silently never matches any keycode passed to `canvas:k_any()`.

**Edit:** I just ran your sample, and indeed calling `iup.key_open()` causes the q and w keys to be recognized. You have a further glitch you will notice next that just updating the paddle's position doesn't ask for the canvas to redraw. I'll leave that as an exercise as you go forward.

**Edit2:** Adding the line `iup.Update(self)` to the function `canvas:k_any()` just after you modify the state of the paddle appears to do what you want. Doing it that way rather than manually calling the `action()` method has the advantage of interacting with IUP's message loop handling in the expected way. In the general case, calling `iup.UpdateChildren(window)` instead might be preferred. That would keep any other IUP controls that are displayed in the dialog updated as well as the canvas, which can be useful if you have controls that don't do all their own updating internally.

Alternatively, you could move the drawing routines into their own function called from both the `k_any()` and `action()` methods of the canvas. I'm not sure I'd recommend that in general as it doesn't scale as well when you want to support multiple viewports or related controls.

You might want to rearrange the logic in your `k_any()` handler so that you are less likely to accidentally forget the call to `iup.Update()` as you add cases for new keys.

Comment: I suspected that the keys were `nil`, thanks for confirming that!  I'm currently looking through the documentation, trying to figure out how to force a redraw, without much luck.  I've tried `iup.Update` and `iup.UpdateChildren`, but it's complaining that they are `nil` values.

Comment: Well, I've managed to make it work, but it seems like it's kinda klunky. At the end of canvas:k_any(), I'm directly calling canvas:action().  This gets the job done, but is there a better way to force a redraw?

Comment: I edited in some explanation about where and how to call iup.Update(self) in the canvas:k_any(key) method.

Comment: iup.key_open() is no longer necessary in IUP 3.